# App crash after sdk upgrade to 30 with DevSupportManager class not found exception

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, crash

im working in a react native app and i upgraded the sdk from 29 to 30, and after that the apps keeps crashing with the below error

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but DevSupportManagerImpl
class was not found or could not be created"

the app works perfectly fine in android 10 and below. it only occurs in android 11

multiDex has already been implemented in the app. if anyone has any suggestions, please share..

Comment: Same issue with our React Native app (freshly created React Native apps work well).

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just needed to bump Flipper to the latest version (while writing `0.102.0`) to fix the issue.

Comment: Mine was 0.37.0. It worked fine after I upgraded to the latest 0.137.0.